# Which remote file managers for Windows don't require port forwarding?

Tags: windows, file-management, remote-access

You should be able to connect to the host computer easily and access all the harddisk, usb-sticks and network drives remotely, without needing to use port forwarding on the router (so no FTP). I do have full control on the server.

Comment: Is Windows the server OS, client OS, or both?

Comment: Windows is both, the server and the cliënt OS.

Comment: Which of the machines is behind a router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com) which is a free remote access software.  All you do is create a account, download the logmein client onto the specified server; then you'll be able to access that server (with full control) from anywhere by just logging into the control panel of the website.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Left us know if you tried either LogMeIn or TeamViewer. @user101579

Comment: LogMeIn is my product of choice, because of the great webbassed gui and the ios apps.

Answer (score 1):

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) is probably the simplest platform in your case.

It includes a VPN feature that is perfect for what you need.